# Acer Aspire One D270 screen crash at wake up

Tags: 12.04, suspend, acer

Yesterday I installed installed ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer aspire one D270-1838.
Everything worked ok, except I couldn't adjust brightness, I fixed it changing:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in grub.

The problem is when I closed the lid it suspended properly but trying to start it again it showed a crashed screen. I have read people with a similar problem but they report screen completely black, mine isn't. I wanted to upload an image of the screen but I don't have the reputation....

Something I can do to suspend my netboot and that works fine is type:

sudo pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on

and it suspends correctly but without authentication, that's not a problem for me but it is tedious. Also, I can enter a virtual terminal with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> which works fine and kill X, this fixes the screen crash but also terminates my session.
however there are sometimes that after the first try if I try to close the lid and open it up again, the screen stays on but black and I cant enter the virtual terminal.

I'm not tech saavy, but I hope you can direct me to a way of fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Permanent activation of "--quirk-dpms-on"

```
$ sudo pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on
```

This solves the problem for me too (thank you for the information).

To permanently activate the solution you have to set it up in `/etc/pm/config.d/defaults`.

I copied the default config file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults` by typing:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults /etc/pm/config.d
```

After that I added the following line at the corresponding place in the file.

```
ADD_PARAMETERS="--quirk-dpms-on"
```

For details see the comments in the file or the manual page of pm-suspend.

have fun ;-)